# Children's book about a boy who breaks his brother's bike pump and stows away on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a short novel, for young readers, in English.

A boy lives on a planet that he thinks is boring. The planet may have a name similar to Omicron. He breaks his big brother's bike pump. Fearing he'll get beaten up for that, he stows away on a spaceship.

While the boy is hiding in the spaceship, he hears the astronauts arguing and brushing their teeth and realises that his heroes are normal people who do normal people stuff like brushing their teeth. The astronauts are actually not very heroic at all.

I read this about 25 years ago, so the chances of it being published in the 80s or early 90s are high.